# how can I set Compare product at bottom in left panel?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the compare product block position at the bottom of the left panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for move sidebar block :

```
<reference name="left_first">
         <action method="unsetChild">
            <alias>catalog.compare.sidebar</alias>
        </action>
        <action method="insert">
            <blockName>catalog.compare.sidebar</blockName>
            <siblingName></siblingName>
            <after>1</after>
        </action>
</reference>
```

Here is full reference for remove child block and add it in new position:

```
<reference name="parent.block.name">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>child_block_alias</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>child.block.name</blockName>
        <siblingName>name_of_block</siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
        <alias>child_block_alias</alias>
    </action>
</reference>
```

This Layout XML instruction does what you want. Look at this short reference of parameters for `insert` method:

- `blockName` is your block unique name across the layout, `product.view` for example
- `siblingName` is an block unique name, that is already exists in insertion target block, used for positioning of your block. Leave empty to display it at the top or at the bottom.
- `after` is a boolean identifier of block position. If equals to `1`, then the block will be added after `siblingName` or in the bottom of the children list if `siblingName` is empty
- `alias` is the alias of your block, if it is empty the name of block will be used.

Some Examples:

**Move cart sidebar block after recently viewed products**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
        <siblingName>right.reports.product.viewed</siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Move cart sidebar block before recently viewed products**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
        <siblingName>right.reports.product.viewed</siblingName>
        <after>0</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Move cart sidebar block at the end of the right block**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
        <siblingName></siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Move cart sidebar block at the top of the left block**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Enjoy working with Magento!

Comment: Yes it's working i have just added. <reference name="left">
            <block type="layerednav/search_layer" name="catalogsearch.layerednav" before="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="layerednav/layer.phtml"/>
    </reference>